# How to call on another function to draw a pie chart?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I am trying to draw a pie chart in Python using turtle. I have the function to draw the chart, but I am making a new function that will take data from a list and draw the slices but I am not understand how I would connect the two. I can only use if statements and for loops and stuff.

I am very new so I can't use anything fancy yet. I think for the algorithm in draw_pie_chart i will calculate the sum of the list then divide first number by the sum so 100/400= .25*360= 90. So my angle will be 90. Just now sure how to do the calling function into the new function for `pie_chart`.

```
def draw_pie_slice(t, center_x, center_y, radius, begin_angle, end_angle, color):
    
    Function draw_pie_slice draws a slice of a pie 

    Parameters:
        t: Reference to a turtle (used for drawing)
        center_x: x coordinate of center of pie
        center_y: y coordinate of center of pie
        radius: radius of pie
        begin_angle: angle where pie piece starts - 0 means on the x axis
        end_angle: angle where pie piece ends
        color: color used to fill the piece
    
    Returns:
        Nothing
    """
    import math
    
    begin_x = radius*math.cos(begin_angle*math.pi/180)
    begin_y = radius*math.sin(begin_angle*math.pi/180)
    arc_angle = end_angle - begin_angle
    
    t.up()
    t.goto(center_x, center_y)
    t.down()
    
    t.fillcolor(color) #set the color used for filling
    t.begin_fill() #mark the beginning of the polygon to be filled
    t.goto(begin_x, begin_y)
    t.setheading(90+begin_angle)
    t.circle(radius, arc_angle)
    t.end_fill() #mark the end of the polygon to be filled. This also causes the polygon drawn to be filled.
    
"""
def draw_pie_chart(t, r, data):
    for r in list ():
        
    
    
    
 
 
 
def main():
    import turtle
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    draw_pie_slice(t, 0, 0, 100, 0, 30, "red")
    draw_pie_slice(t, 0, 0, 100, 30, 90, "blue")
    draw_pie_slice(t, 0, 0, 100, 90, 170, "green")
    draw_pie_chart(100,200,100)
    draw_pie_chart(20,20,40,10,30)

main()
```

"""

Comment: Google charts are easy to use and it's really cool. I recommend you to do some research about it, maybe you could combine it with your project (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Comment: @Hani So the exercise on the website I am learning wont let me use anything but the previous function. I can only call on that function in the new one.

Comment: @martineau I didnt find an existing tutorial

Comment: What you want to know how to do — making one function call another and pass it data — will be covered in the vast majority of Python tutorials. It's a core programming concept available in most computer languages. Functions are also called [subroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine).